# Show/hide with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to show or hide unordered lists, based on when someone clicks a heading. I've found a way to do this, which would work fine for a single list. As I have multiple lists, it's not very efficient. Please forgive the ugly table code - that doesn't exist in the real page:

https://jsfiddle.net/eug7LLuq/1/

I've also added the fake code below.

I'm working with someone else's code, so unfortunately:

- I can't add a class  to the unordered lists
- I can't change the IDs of the unordered lists
- I cannot make the unordered lists children of other list items (as in some of the other questions I've seen posed here)

I do have control over the 'heading' code in the fiddle, and the JS.

Can you advise me on a more efficient way of accomplishing this? Thanks in advance.

```
<style>
#s-lg-link-list-539480, #s-lg-link-list-539482 {
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var $list = $("#s-lg-link-list-539480");
var $list2 = $("#s-lg-link-list-539482");
$("#tog-link-1").bind('click', function () {
    $list.slideToggle();
})
$("#tog-link-2").bind('click', function () {
    $list2.slideToggle();
}) 
});
</script> 
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p><a href="#" id="tog-link-1">Heading 1</a>

                    <br /> <a href="#" id="tog-link-2">Heading 2</a>

                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul id="s-lg-link-list-539480">
                    <li><a href="http://www.one.com">One</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.two.com">Two</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.three.com">Three</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="s-lg-link-list-539482">
                    <li><a href="http://www.four.com">Four</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.five.com">Five</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.six.com">Six</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you already have?

Comment: @blubberguy22: It works, but I suspect it's not the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generalize the action, maybe you can add a class like "list-toggler" to each of your `a` elements and also a custom `data` attribute mapping them to a `ul`, like `data-associated-list="#s-lg-link-list-539480"`. Then you could simplify your JS as something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.listToggler').bind('click', function() {
      $($(this).data('associated-list')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eug7LLuq/4/)

Not sure if this is your problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/eug7LLuq/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[id^='tog']").bind('click', function (e) {
        var getIdNumber = e.target.id.slice(-1);
        $('ul:nth-child(' + getIdNumber + ')').slideToggle();
    })
});
```